# Error in SSL handshake with OpenSSL 1.0.2j (26 Sep 2016) using Net::SSLeay perl module

Tags: perl, ssl, openssl

I am sending a request locally(tomcat 8.5.40 is running in background)  using Net::SSLeay perl module(8.5 version) and I am getting this response:

```
[8618] 2019/10/16 18:36:39.889  Response:HTTP/1.0   900 NET OR SSL ERROR

SSL_connect 8618: 1 - error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
SSL_connect 8618: 2 - error:1408D010:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:EC lib
```

What can be the issue here? 
**This perl script is executing on Centos 8 machine.**

Comment: [Redhat crippled the library.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1019390) Please add the output of `openssl ciphers`. Also see: https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools